# PHP upload files to path as full domain address

Tags: php

I am using PHP to upload files onto my web server from a subdomain.

my subdomain is `admin.domain.com` which is located in the directory admin before the `public_html` directory (i am using cPanel)

i want to be able to upload files into the `admin` directory which is up a level from the public_html directory from `admin.domain.com` and also from just `domain.com`

what path names will i need to use to do this?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and see what it returns? Couldn't you just add an extra `../`?

Comment: `<form action="http://domain.com" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your files are in the same server, in the same file structure, just being seen through differents domains. If yes, then what you need to check is:

**1 - The path for the admin directoy, for example: F:/wamp/www/php/super-variables/test-$_server.php**

For that, you can throw a php file with `<?php echo ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]; ?>` in the folder. It will return the path for that folder.

**2 - Check if you have permission to upload files in that folder:**

For that, It will depend on how much permission you have in your server. I use the Filezilla FTP to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`$uploadPath = realpath( __DIR__ . '/..' );`

Answer (score 0):

set your path in a variable and use `move_uploaded_file()` to move your file in desired location every time you upload any file.